# JSON Object to Jquery select array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON object where it's stringify is as like in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/2289/

I would like to parse it to key value array,so that I could store in select box.

Below is what I expect to have

```
var convertedArray = {
  'VAS_1000' : 'AMC',
  'VAS_1001' : 'EW',
  'VAS_1002' : 'EW',
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`Array.prototype.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

```js
var o = {"tuple":[{"old":{"MST_VAS_TYPE":{"MST_VAS_TYPE_ID":"VAS_1000","VAS_TYPE_NAME":"AMC","VAS_TYPE_DESC":"Annual Maintenance Contract","CREATED_ON":null,"CREATED_BY":null,"MODIFIED_ON":null,"MODIFIED_BY":null,"@xmlns":"http://services.vw.com/lpms/1.0/wsapp"}},"@xmlns":"http://services.vw.com/lpms/1.0/wsapp"},{"old":{"MST_VAS_TYPE":{"MST_VAS_TYPE_ID":"VAS_1001","VAS_TYPE_NAME":"EW","VAS_TYPE_DESC":"Extended Warranty","CREATED_ON":null,"CREATED_BY":null,"MODIFIED_ON":null,"MODIFIED_BY":null,"@xmlns":"http://services.vw.com/lpms/1.0/wsapp"}},"@xmlns":"http://services.vw.com/lpms/1.0/wsapp"},{"old":{"MST_VAS_TYPE":{"MST_VAS_TYPE_ID":"VAS_1002","VAS_TYPE_NAME":"COUPON","VAS_TYPE_DESC":"Recall","CREATED_ON":null,"CREATED_BY":null,"MODIFIED_ON":null,"MODIFIED_BY":null,"@xmlns":"http://services.vw.com/lpms/1.0/wsapp"}},"@xmlns":"http://services.vw.com/lpms/1.0/wsapp"}],"@xmlns:SOAP":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","@xmlns":"http://services.vw.com/lpms/1.0/wsapp"};
a= o.tuple.map(function(val){
  var inner = val['old']['MST_VAS_TYPE'];
  var ret = {};
  ret[inner["MST_VAS_TYPE_ID"]] = inner['VAS_TYPE_NAME'];
  return ret;
})
sel = document.createElement("select");
document.body.appendChild(sel);
for (var index in a) {
  obj = a[index];
  for (var prop in obj){
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = obj[prop];
    option.value = prop;
    sel.appendChild(option);
  }
}
//console.log(a);
```

Comment: When binding to select box,the value comes like 0,1,2 .here is the fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/2293/

Comment: @user1650864 I updated the answer. Can you check?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the example I put the string in div to get it easily into the script.

I'm using [`eval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) to convert it to a javascript object.

After you have to object you can iterate his properties using [`for -> in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and generate html for each to `option` tag.

Finally, put the html into the `select` tag.

```js
eval(document.querySelector('div').innerText);

var sel = document.querySelector('select'),
    html = '';

for (var item in convertedArray) {
    html += '<option value="' + item + '">' + convertedArray[item] + '</option>';
}

sel.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div>
  var convertedArray = {
  'VAS_1000' : 'AMC',
  'VAS_1001' : 'EW',
  'VAS_1002' : 'EW',
  }
</div>
<select>
  
</select>
```